# Hibernate could not create connection to databaseserver

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

I wrote a programm with hibernate. I backed it up on a harddisk as war. Now my Server is not working more so I want it to install on a other server, but I become this exception:

> I think it's a problem of a MySql configuration, cause de programm works perfect. Do someone have a idea?

```
    TeilnehmerDAO tdao = new TeilnehmerDAO();

    Teilnehmer t = new Teilnehmer();

    t.setBeruf("d");
    t.setEintrittsjahr(2017);
    t.setFachrichtung("dd");
    t.setKlasse("Api17a");
    t.setMail("dd.dd@dd.com");
    t.setName("dd");
    t.setPasswort("BlaBla");
    t.setVorname("dd");

    tdao.insert(t);

    System.out.println("Fertig");
    tdao.getEntityManagerFactory().close();




<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="org.hibernate.tutorial.jpa">
    <description>
       Hibernate
    </description>
    <class>ch.matovic.bean.Event</class>
    <class>ch.matovic.bean.Kategorie</class>
    <class>ch.matovic.bean.Teilnehmer</class>
    <class>ch.matovic.bean.Event_Teilnehmer</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
            value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Hibernate" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password"
            value="123456789" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect"
            value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

```
Sep. 14, 2018 5:38:44 NACHM. org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: org.hibernate.tutorial.jpa
    ...]
Sep. 14, 2018 5:38:44 NACHM. org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.10.Final}
Sep. 14, 2018 5:38:44 NACHM. org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Sep. 14, 2018 5:38:44 NACHM. org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Sep. 14, 2018 5:38:44 NACHM. org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Sep. 14, 2018 5:38:44 NACHM. org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Hibernate]
Sep. 14, 2018 5:38:44 NACHM. org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=root}
Sep. 14, 2018 5:38:44 NACHM. org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Sep. 14, 2018 5:38:44 NACHM. org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at ch.matovic.dao.TeilnehmerDAO.<init>(TeilnehmerDAO.java:26)
    at ch.matovic.start.Index.run(Index.java:19)
    at ch.matovic.start.Index.<init>(Index.java:9)
    at ch.matovic.start.Index.main(Index.java:13)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1023)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:997)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:983)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:928)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2576)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2309)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:419)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharset(ConnectionImpl.java:3299)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendConnectionAttributes(MysqlIO.java:1967)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1893)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1287)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2494)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2527)
    ... 43 more
```

Kind regars, thaaaanks

Comment: Can you Ping it, and connect via Telnet?

Comment: can you share the code ?

Comment: I‘m using the programm and the MySql on the same device. IF I put an other IP-Adress into the persistence.xml(configurationfile) I get an error that the programm can‘t gett access to the DB server.

Comment: sure I can share my code

Comment: in localhost does it work ?

Comment: Are the two IPs under the same network?

Comment: yes it should work

Comment: then, MySQL on the other host does not accept connections other than localhost

Comment: yes they are on the same device and in the same network

Comment: do not understand me worng, the programm worked on the old server(device) so now its on a new device. The programm should work perfekt with the value localhost

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet" value="utf8"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="utf8"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true"/>
```

and change

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Hibernate?characterEncoding=utf8" />
```

Comment: I copied this into my persistence.xml with this pattern: `<property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet" value="utf8" />` cause your pattern gives an error in eclipse.
So sadly with your configuration changes it also does not work :(

Comment: I change  my answer, try again and if does not work, try to change just javax.persistence.jdbc.url

Comment: I deleted the properties and changed only the javax.persistence.jdbc.url, but it also does not work.

Comment: what is your mysql version and connector version?